# Filtering Pivot Tables with filter criteria on multiple fields

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I am creating a marketing spreadsheet for the office. There are two main things I am having difficulty accomplishing:

1) Creating a dashboard of pivot charts from source data (~3000 lines)
  2) Filtering that data by sales rep, month, and quarter

I have been working in excel and with tables for about 6 months, and am fairly comfortable working with tables, pivot tables, and charts for the aforementioned; but I have only recently begun to learn VBA scripting to create macros.

My question is this: how can I apply more than one filter per table using buttons. In other words, I want to be able to click `button A` that filters sales for Jim. Then I want to be able to click another button, `button B`, that, in addition to filtering sales for Jim, filters sales for Janet as well.

Another idea I had is using checkboxes to create multiple filters for each chart, but I do not know how to use checkboxes with pivot tables.

I cannot use slicers due to compatibility issues (Mac, Excel older than '07, etc.) Can this be done?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I don't have ready access to Excel, but in LibreOffice Calc, there is an option on the initial layout page to include filters (and LO Calc is typically a subset of Excel).  You drag whatever fields you want to filter to the Page window and each gets a filter pulldown.  Assuming that's included in Excel, it's a trivial step to add the multiple field filtering, and no VBA is required.

Answer (score 0):

*I would like to suggest you a Solution which is much easier and faster. If you use this VBA code then you don't need to create many buttons.*

**All you have to do.**

1. Select the entire Data Range including Header Rows and either go to the Name Box or hit Formula TAB and pick, Define Name and **NAME the Data Range**.
2. Copy this VBA code using VBE (Visual Basic Editor).
3. If every thing is Ready Double Click the NAME of the SALE Man.

Excel will Filter records, using the NAME been clicked.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)

    Dim rgTable As Range
    Dim rgData As Range
    Dim xColumn As Integer

    On Error Resume Next

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set rgTable = Range("SALES")

    With rgTable
        Set rgData = .Offset(1, 0).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, .Columns.Count)

        If Not Application.Intersect(ActiveCell, rgData.Cells) Is Nothing Then
            xColumn = ActiveCell.Column - .Column + 1

            If ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False Then
                .AutoFilter
            End If

            If ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Filters(xColumn).On = True Then
                .AutoFilter Field:=xColumn
            Else
                .AutoFilter Field:=xColumn, Criteria1:=ActiveCell.Value
            End If
        End If

    End With

    Set rgData = Nothing
    Set rgTable = Nothing

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

[image]

**NB:**

*1.This Code was tested by me, before I've posted it here as the Solution.*

*2. I'm suggesting Double click method, on the basis of your requirements.*

*3. Actually, using this code Excel filters records on SALES MAN NAME only, means it's SINGLE CRITERIA Filter. If you want to add more Criteria then the Code need to be REVISED.*

**Hope this help you.**

Comment: Thank you for all you posted, it really helps a lot with building my understanding of VBA, but I need there to be multiple search criteria that is flexible. For instance, I would like to press a button to filter by, say, Salesperson 1. Then, without overriding the previous filter, click another button and filter by salesperson 2 simultaneously.

Comment: Nice to hear from you and really happy to learn that you found my Solution useful. My first expectation is Vote it as answer. This encourage me  and others too.

Comment: It's very much possible to Filter on multiple Criteria, actually in OP you have mentioned one Field, Salesman name. It's easy, let me explain how could you achieve it ? If you want to Filter name after other then the current code should need lil modification, like after first filter, get all records and select other name. If you want multi Field Filter then bunch of lines need to add here. What I would like to suggest, try once, if not get through, write here I'll support you.